# Oracle generate list of IW week dates

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

Goal: 
Output a list of IW standard week dates for a given time range based off of the current date.

Desired output: with Current date = 4/27/2012, list of past 7 IW week dates

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
    SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE - (LEVEL * 7), 'IW') TheDate
      FROM dual
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew there would be a simplified and better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm using this code to generate the list. I'm curious if there is a better solution. But wanted to provide this solution to anyone who may be looking.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  TRUNC(sysdate-(rownum+1),'iw') IW_week,
  TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate-(rownum+1),'iw'),'iw') AS week_num
FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level <= 49
ORDER BY TRUNC(sysdate-(rownum+1),'iw');
```

Current output:

[image]