# return zero when grouping by week after select -

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sequential

I have some code below

```
select 
'WEEK '|| row_number() over(order by trunc(NEXT_DAY(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY'),'SATURDAY'), 'IW')) WEEK,
count(*) 
from opencall
where trunc(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY')) BETWEEN '01-JAN-14' AND '31-DEC-14'
group by trunc(NEXT_DAY(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY'),'SATURDAY'), 'IW')   
order by trunc(NEXT_DAY(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY'),'SATURDAY'), 'IW');
```

Which is a great piece of code that another stackoverflow chap wrote for me for extracting calls from the database and counting / grouping them by week and it works perfectly if there are always calls in every week.

However I've tried reusing this code for other uses and if there is no result in a given week I get fewer groupings i.e. perhaps only 37 weeks returned instead of the current 50 weeks for instance.

As this is removing the weeks where there are no calls the week numbers dont equate to real week numbers in the year.  So I don't actually know what weeks the calls are being returned from as the weeks remain sequential rather than having zeros in the weeks with no calls.

Is there any way to return a zero value if there are no results returned for a given week?  I imagine that may make the code much more complex.

If I am using this code over a week

e.g:

```
WEEK 1  231
WEEK 2  657
WEEK 3  529
WEEK 4  606
WEEK 5  594
WEEK 6  517
WEEK 7  683
WEEK 8  664
WEEK 9  583
WEEK 10 740
```

Comment: So is the first week in the year part of last year or current year?  So say Jan 1st - Jan 3rd 2015 is week 52 of 2014 while Jan 4th-10th is week 1 of 2015?  The problem you have is that you need to make up the data for each week so you can left join opencall to it.  this way the weeks are always 52.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354600/oracle-generate-list-of-iw-week-dates shows you how to generate 7 weeks, change 7 to 52 and left join to open call and you'll be close, you'll just need to extract the week of year from the date.

Comment: _"Which is a great piece of code that another stackoverflow chap wrote for me"_ Please consider accepting [the answer that solved your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27490218/2363712). See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know which week you are showing, then why the fuss with row_number()?

This gives you the year separated in weeks, starting with the first seven days make week 1 and so on:

```
select to_char(mydate, 'ww'), count(*)
from 
(
  select to_date(substr(logdate,1,10), 'dd-mm-yy') as mydate
  from opencall
)
where extract(year from mydate) = 2014
group by to_char(mydate, 'ww')
order by to_char(mydate, 'ww');
```

(Why is LOGDATE a string? And why are its first 10 characters in the format 'DD-MM-YY' which is 8 characters long?)

Comment: The call management system saves the data as varchar, no idea why its just the way it is.

Comment: Hi Thorston.  Sorry to sound like an idiot, But were you expecting the code provided above to work for me?  I tried running it and oracle complained YEAR was an invalid identifier.

Comment: Haha, sorry, the idiot was me. There is no YEAR function in Oracle. Please use either `where extract(year from mydate) = 2014` or `where to_char(mydate,'yyyy') = '2014'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  How is this doing its week i.e. is it monday to monday , friday to friday?  Also is there any way for it to return a 0 if there is no data for a given week.  I.e. one user I am experimenting with doesn't have any calls until week 10, so I'd really like it to return 0 for those weeks or subsequent weeks when he is on holiday for instance.  Is that possible?

Comment: It starts at 1.1.2014 to 7.1.2014 as the first week of 2014, no matter what weekdays. The good thing about this is that it is the same for every year (with week 53 always being very short). If you used ISO weeks instead for example, sometimes the first week would be short, sometimes the last.

Comment: I see.  Is there any way to move the 1st day out to be a specific day to coincide with my KPI week. Otherwise it looks like it goes from wednesday to wednesday and my KPI week is say Saturday to Friday if you see what I mean.  Cheers

Comment: Also did u think it was easy to get a zero return for a week with no values? I'm after this as its then easier to work with excel based charts where I can have more than one member of staff on the same chart.  If the weeks don't match up it wont work.  Cheers

Comment: SQL only gives you data which exists. So, as there are numbers missing, easiest would be to use a programming language to fill the gaps. If you want it done in the dmbs then you could create a table for the weeks containing the values 1 to 53. Then left join above query to it. There are also techniques to generate 53 numbers on-the fly (`select rownum from bigtable where rownum <= 53` or a recursive query).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I think I'll need to try and keep it simple.  Some great tips.  Hopefully by this time next year I'll understand what most of them do ;o).  However, in the mean time I have what I need so thank you very much and Happy Christmas.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
'WEEK '|| row_number() over(order by trunc(NEXT_DAY(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY'),'SATURDAY'), 'IW')) WEEK,
row_number() over(order by trunc(NEXT_DAY(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY'),'SATURDAY'), 'IW')) mWeek, 
count(*) 
from (SELECT to_char(SYSDATE - (LEVEL * 7),'IW') TheDate
      FROM dual
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 52) WoY
LEFT JOIN opencall
  on Woy.TheDate = OpenCall.mWeek
where trunc(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY')) BETWEEN '01-JAN-14' AND '31-DEC-14'
group by trunc(NEXT_DAY(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY'),'SATURDAY'), 'IW')   
order by trunc(NEXT_DAY(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY'),'SATURDAY'), 'IW');
```

Something like this may work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this with test data and works. I hope this works for you too:

```
select 
'WEEK '|| row_number() over(order by nvl(to_char(NEXT_DAY(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY') ,'SATURDAY'), 'IW'),week)) WEEK
,count(wk) 
from (select t.*,to_char(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY'),'IW') wk,w.week from
      table1 t right join (SELECT lpad(level,2,0) week
      FROM dual
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 52 ) w on (to_char(to_date(substr(t.LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY'),'IW') = w.week)
      order by w.week)
where trunc(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY')) BETWEEN '01-JAN-14' AND '31-DEC-14'
group by nvl(to_char(NEXT_DAY(to_date(substr(LOGDATE,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY') ,'SATURDAY'), 'IW'),week)   
;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your feedback.  It doesn't seem to work and my SQL isn't good enough to work out why.

Answer (score -1):

--Creating a test table under schema alber and inserting data on it for all days on weeks multiple of 4.

```
create table alber.week_table (mydate date, mydescription varchar2(100));
declare
cur_date date :=  to_date('01/01/'||to_char(sysdate,'yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy') ;
week number := 01;
begin
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE alber.week_table';
  while (cur_date < sysdate) loop
    if mod(week,4) = 0 then
      insert into alber.week_table values(cur_date, to_char(sysdate, 'day dd month yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))  ;
    end if; 
    cur_date := cur_date + 1;
    week := to_number(to_char(cur_date,'IW'));
  end loop;  
end;
```

--Then one possible solution would be:

```
select theweek "Week", sum( decode( nvl(mydescription,0),'0',0,1) ) "Num of Records" 
FROM 
    (
      SELECT to_char(SYSDATE - (LEVEL * 7),'IW') theweek
      FROM dual
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 52
     ) w
LEFT JOIN  week_table ON w.theweek =  to_char(mydate,'IW')   
group by theweek
order by 1;
```

Result

```
Week Num of Records         
---- ---------------------- 
01   0                      
02   0                      
03   0                      
04   7                      
05   0                      
06   0                      
07   0                      
08   7                      
09   0                      
10   0                      
11   0                      
12   7                      
13   0                      
14   0                      
15   0                      
16   7                      
17   0                      
18   0        
.
.
.
```

Comment: I only have read only access to the data I am afraid so I can't create tables but thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Anthony, the ideia of creating a table was just to ilustrate the solution.  You don't have to create a table, it is just to use the same idea on your own tables.

Comment: I appreciate that.  My SQL skills aren't massively extensive at the moment so I'm trying to find a simple solution.  I'm amazed it isn't easier as it seems to be a common requirement eh.  Thanks